# What is the ritual component cost "set of focuses"?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

In D&D 4th edition, the Alarm ritual has a component cost of "5gp, plus a set of focuses." What does "set of focuses" refer to here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compendium entry for the Alarm ritual states:

> Focus: While holding a tiny bell (5 gp), you use a fine silver wire (5 gp) to scribe runes on the warded area’s perimeter.

So I'd hazard that the set means both items.

Comment: So, in other words, a nice DM will just let you spend 15gp to use the ritual instead of requiring you to have everything already on you.

Comment: A nice DM will make it interesting and not boring to find the elements, but yes. Otherwise, why bother with the ritual at all?

Comment: Note that focuses, unlike components, are not consumed during a ritual, so you only have to acquire them once.